# Как сверстать данные блоки, как вырезать один элемент из другого

Tags: вёрстка

Мне нужно сверстать 3 блока, только при вёрстке круга нужно чтобы я видел фон не зелёный, а фон самого внешнего блока(красного).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать 'box-shadow'

```css
.block {
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 32px;
}

.hasCircle {
  width: 480px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.hasCircle:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 100px auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1000px #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="hasCircle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо большое, можно я чуть что вас потревожу, если возникнут вопросы?)

Comment: @Vadim если будут свободен то с радостью помогу

Comment: вы не подскажите как убрать вот данные линии, образующие квадрат https://pastenow.ru/dc1b0dbdfe3f8481449b5e14239d99c1.